# SLES 10 SP4 - how to get specific kernel source?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, sles

I want to look at the kernel source for some specific [kernel versions](http://wiki.novell.com/index.php/Kernel_versions) on SLES 10 SP4.

I don't want to see just the [Linux kernel source](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/), but the one SLES is actually running. Suppose I wanted to get `kernel-source-2.6.16.60-0.103.1.x86_64.rpm`, how would I do that? (is that the right rpm name?)

I have the source for `linux-2.6.16.60-0.85.1` installed, and I can view that, so I'm hoping it is possible to view the source for the other versions.

I've been looking around [this repository](http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/discontinued/source/distribution/) hoping to find something useful. I've been playing around with `zypper`, `yast2`, and `rug`.

**How do I download the kernel source for a specific kernel version on SLES 10 SP4?**

I did see some other similar questions on here about the source for the Linux Kernel, but I'm interested in the ones that have patches for SLES on top of them.

Comment: `zypper se kernel-source` should show you the available source packages for the kernel available in the repos.

Comment: Thanks @schaiba, I did try that actually and I only get one result: `2.6.16.60-0.85.1`. Any idea on how I can get the updated versions?

Comment: Is your repository metadata up-to-date? `zypper up` just to make sure.

Comment: @schaiba thanks! I ran `zypper up` and it says `Summary: Nothing to do.` so it seems to be up to date.

Comment: If memory serves, `zypper rl` would display the installed repos. Please paste that here.

Comment: @schaiba `zypper rl` must be newer. I can list installation sources with `zypper sl`. It lists two, one is `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP4 | cd:///?devices=/dev/sr0` and the other is an iso `iso:///?iso=(didn't want to post the location)`. Is it possible to add an online repository? I see there is an `service-add` option.

Comment: I only used OpenSUSE, not SLES, so I can't really comment on these differences between them.